# Mongo find operation returns documents (objects). How to access this?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I search for a document in my mongo collection given a property value. I wish to save that document and spit out a property it contains. How can I go about this? I know it is very simple, but I must be doing something wrong

FYI, I am very new to mongo atm :) - using meteorjs

Here is the code:

```
var show = "The Walking Dead";
var TVShowObject = TVShow_List.find( {name: show} ); 
var channel_property = TVShowObject.channel;
```

and the mongo document is returned:

```
{ 
"_id": ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"),
"name": "The Walking Dead",
"channel": "AMC"
}
```

For some reason, the channel property is not being stored into `channel_property` variable. Any thoughts?

Comment: because you get an iterator back not a single document, you need to foreach the iterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collection.find` returns a `LocalCursor` not a document, you need to use `Collection.findOne` :

```
var TVShowObject = TVShow_List.findOne( {name: show} );
// displays "AMC"
console.log(TVShowObject);
```

If the find operation is expected to return multiple documents, you need to use `LocalCursor.forEach` :

```
var cursor = TVShow_List.find({name:show});
cursor.forEach(function(tvShow){
  console.log(tvShow.channel);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to use `fetch()` an array of Objects, if used after `find()`. Or if you expect only one result, in most cases `findOne()` is better.

```
var TVShowObject = TVShow_List.find( {name: show} ).fetch();
```